# How to use pickle to serialize this object?

Tags: python, pickle

```
I have a big text file, space delimited like below:


 This is a test
 This is a second test
 And this is a third test
```

I need to read each line into a list, so the first line would be:

```
["This, "is",  "a",  "test"]
```

And the whole file will be read into a list:

```
content = [[,,,], [,,,], [,,,] ]
```

This file is one 1G big and every time when I run the program, it takes a long time to just load this file into the list for initialization.

```
class FileLoader(object):

     def __init__(object):
        self.content_list = load('./file_path')

     def load(file_path):
        content_list = []
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
           for line in f:
               words = line.split(' ')
               content_list.append(words)
        return content_list
```

I haven't ever used pickle abut I head pickle can serialize object and make the reading much faster. Is that true and how to do that?

Comment: do you need the file all at once?

Comment: Yes. I want to load everything into memory to speed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pickle the thing, set it up in the list form you want, then

```
import pickle
open(‘myFile.pickle’,’wb’).write(  pickle.dumps(myGiantList)  )
```

It is the same as json, but with the word pickle.
You can also `pickle.dump(myGiantList,’myFile.pickle’)`.
Make sure to check out the docs if you haven’t.
Pickling isn’t the best for size, and to append data to an already pickled file requires some gyrating. Also a one gig file in memory is a one gig file in memory; but try it out and see if pickling suits your intent.